# File list by ls are misaligned

Tags: linux, ls

I *catted* a binary file and hit Ctrl-Z to stop it.  Now ls results are misaligned.  What did it happen and how could I have them listed correctly again ?

Answer (score 9):

Type `reset` to reset your terminal, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  Then maybe press <kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd> to clear the screen.  You should be back to normal.

Oh and by the way, that binary cat you ran, when you pressed <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> that just suspended it, it's probably still running.  Run `jobs` to see the list of jobs, and if it's there, say job number 2, do `kill %2` (or whichever job number).

Answer (score 1):

When you `cat`ted the binary file, your terminal probably inadvertently interpreted some of its data as [control sequences](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/terminalcodes) and tried to execute them, screwing its properties and state.

You can either kill the terminal altogether (quit it if you're in a GUI, or relog if you're on a tty), or use another control sequence to reset the terminal. `echo -e \\033c` should do the trick. Some systems also have a `reset` builtin/command, which accomplishes the same thing.